# 16 Congruent Scalene Integer Triangles

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, triangles, polyhedra, solid-geometry

With any triangle, [8 copies can make an octahedron](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/OctahedraConstructedFromEightIdenticalTriangles/). With any acute triangle, 4 copies can make a tetrahedron.

Make a scalene octahedron, then construct scalene tetrahedra on each face.  Here are samples with the 4-5-6, 6-12-13, 9-11-13, 11-12-15, and 11-13-16 triangles.
[image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

These are cases where we almost get a 16-triangle outer shell. None of them quite works, the outermost vertices don't actually coincide in these cases.

Is there an integer triangle that gives a perfect solution?

Comment: At first congruent triangles make tetrahedra of 4 equal face. Although you try to make  concave hexahedron on each face, such a shape doesn't exist. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexahedron.